# std::tm to std::time_t conversion gives error for a specific date before 1970 (c++)

Tags: c++, datetime, timestamp

I'm currently trying to store birth dates via `time_t`. For that purpose, I'm also using `std::mktime` and `std::tm`. However, when I try to convert a specific date from `std::tm` to `std::time_t`, it returns `-1`, which indicates that the conversion was not successful. I know that Unix timestamps should store the number of seconds from Jan 1, 1970 UTC, but I could not find any reference indicating that negative timestamps are not allowed.
Why is this happening? Should I use another alternative for storing birth dates?

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int year = 1914;
    int month = 1;
    int day = 1;

    std::tm tm{};
    std::time_t timestamp;
    tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = month - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = day;
    timestamp = std::mktime(&tm);

    std::cout << timestamp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is unchartered territory. If this is not supported by your C++ library, that's pretty much it. It's not supported.

Comment: [Chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (and Calendar if your tools really are up to date (and if they are not, here's [`date`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date))) may be helpful to you.

Comment: I think you'll find that `time_t` is not suitable for your purposes, unless all the birthdates are on-or-after 1970.

Comment: I would set  `tm.tm_isdst = -1;` in any case before calling `mktime` unless you do know that DST was not in effect for the date.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me (GCC 11 Linux). What compiler are you using?

Comment: my compiler is GCC 9.3.0 Linux

Comment: A potential problem with this approach is that one will get different values if the computer crosses a time zone boundary as `mktime` subtracts the local UTC offset in the computation of the `time_t`.  It might be better to store a count of _days_ before/after 1970-01-01 instead of a count of seconds.

Comment: I see...
Helpfui tips indeed. I'll check out the mentioned `date` library.

Comment: We may also try boost [gregorian](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_class) date, it supports year with range (1400, 9999), seems to be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in storing dates as a count of days using the [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)<sup>1</sup> library, here's what it would look like:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    namespace chr = date;
//  namespace chr = std::chrono;

    int year = 1914;
    int month = 1;
    int day = 1;

    chr::sys_days timestamp = chr::year{year}/month/day;
    int intstamp = timestamp.time_since_epoch()/chr::days{1};

    std::cout << intstamp << '\n';

    chr::year_month_day recover_birthday = chr::sys_days{chr::days{intstamp}};
    assert(year  ==      int{recover_birthday.year()});
    assert(month == unsigned{recover_birthday.month()});
    assert(day   == unsigned{recover_birthday.day()});

    std::cout << "min date = "  << chr::year::min()/01/01 << '\n';
    std::cout << "max date =  " << chr::year::max()/12/31 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
-20454
min date = -32767-01-01
max date =  32767-12-31
```

Above I show the conversion both ways:

1. From `{year, month, day}` to `int`
2. From `int` to `{year, month, day}`

I've also added the self-documenting range of validity for the `{year, month, day}` data structure.

This will work with C++11/14/17.  [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)<sup>1</sup> is an open-source, free, header-only library, no installation required.  Just `#include "date/date.h"`.  If you need time zone support (this example doesn't), then there is an additional, non-header-only library also available at this same link.

If you would rather not use [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)<sup>1</sup>, the algorithms it wraps to do this computation are documented [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).

The [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)<sup>1</sup> library is also a preview of [C++20 `<chrono>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.cal).  To port the above program to C++20, drop `#include "date/date.h"` and change `namespace chr = date;` to `namespace chr = std::chrono;`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Full disclosure: I am the lead author of this library. I am not pursuing any financial gain from this effort. But sometimes people get grumpy if I don't fully disclose this information.